# Ошибка с Pipe() в multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

**Main.py**

```
from Test import *
if __name__=="__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    p_out, p_in = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(p_in,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(p_out,))
    p2.start()
    p1.start()

    def test1bind():
        print("F pressed")
        global p1
        if p1.is_alive():
            p1.terminate()
        else:
            p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(p_in,))
            p1.start()

    def test2bind():
        print("G pressed")
        global p2
        p2.terminate()
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(p_out,))
        p2.start()

    import keyboard
    keyboard.add_hotkey("F", test1bind)
    keyboard.add_hotkey("G", test2bind)
```

**Test.py**

```
from time import sleep

def test1(p_in):
    test = 0
    while True:
        sleep(0.012)
        test = test + 1
        p_in.send(test)

def test2(p_out):
    while True:
        img = p_out.recv()
        print(img)
```

Я получаю ошибку, если нажимаю сперва F а потом G:

```
F pressed
G pressed

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.875 s
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . . Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 102, in spawn_main
    source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
OSError: [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно
```

Но если я нажму сперва G а потом F, то получаю другую ошибку:

```
F pressed

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 1.058 s
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 312, in _recv_bytes
    nread, err = ov.GetOverlappedResult(True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] Канал был закрыт

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\1NAIM\NAIM\HELP\Test.py", line 12, in test2
    img = p_out.recv()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 321, in _recv_bytes
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Я не понимаю, почему она появляется. Я могу много раз закрывать например p1, и ошибок не будет, стоит мне закрыть их, в любом порядке, как возникает ошибка.

Comment: Каналы нельзя переиспользовать. Весь канал переводится в недействительное состояние, если один из пользователей на его закрыл. [похожая ситуация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666659/broken-pipe-error-when-reusing-the-same-pipe-inside-a-loop)

Comment: Посмотрите на [os.mkfifo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo). С ним не должно быть таких проблем.

Comment: Я могу закрыть несколько раз процесс, который отдаёт эти данные в "Канал" Но я не могу закрыть другой канал, если запущу сперва тот который "отдаёт".
То есть, я нажимаю G, и он заново открывается, и всё работает же. В чём проблема, не понятна. Ну ладно, спасибо, буду надеется что кто нибудь ещё напишет что нибудь важно. А пока я буду пробовать исправить проблему. Хотя понятия не имею как : )

Comment: `os.mkfifo` создаёт постоянный канал, над ним можно издеваться куда больше.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста изменить пример кода, с использованием этого, а то не могу понять. И если это решит проблему, я отмечу его как "решение" : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал "Костыль", **но всё ещё жду более лучшего ответа:**

**Main.py**

```
from Test import *
if __name__=="__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    p_out, p_in = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(p_in,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(p_out,))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=menu)
    p2.start()
    p1.start()
    p3.start()
    def test1bind():
        print("F pressed")
        global p1
        global p2
        if p1.is_alive():
            p1.terminate()
            p2.terminate()
        else:
            p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(p_in,))
            p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(p_out,))
            p1.start()
            p2.start()

    def test2bind():
        print("G pressed")
        global p1
        global p2
        p1.terminate()
        p2.terminate()
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(p_in,))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(p_out,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()

    import keyboard
    keyboard.add_hotkey("F", test1bind)
    keyboard.add_hotkey("G", test2bind)
```

**Test.py**

```
from time import sleep

def test1(p_in):
    test = 0
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        test = test + 1
        p_in.send(test)

def test2(p_out):
    while True:
        img = p_out.recv()
        print(img)

def menu():
    sleep(99999)
```

p.s. нужен фоновый процесс, иначе программа будет закрываться.

Comment: Похоже. Всё таки, не кто не даст ответ, я помечу свой вариант как решение, если кто то всё же напишет что то лучше, поставлю галочку : )